# R Package passing function through to new function

Tags: r, r-package

I'm creating a new package as a learning exercise. I've selected a few functions that serve the purpose I need and want to bundle them together into a single, new, package that I can then apply gWidgets to to make them GUI driven.

Finding documentation on how to pass existing functions has been pretty sparse and I am a novice at this. Any assistance would be appreciated.

I've added the necessary imports in my Description using `usethis:use_package()` updated the NAMESPACE (using Roxygen)
and created the .R files using a Stackoverflow as a framework. a sample .R looks like this:

```
#'ODBC list drivers
#'
#'@export
odbcListDrivers <- function() {
odbc::odbcListDrivers()
}
```

This Works.
But when it comes to the point I need to pass information with a more advanced function:

```
#'    
#' u/export    
#'    
DBconnect <- function() {    
DBI::dbConnect()    
}
```

I get an unused argument error when I try to run the test code.

```
con <- DBconnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),    
+ dbname = "sakila",    
+ host = "192.168.50.71",    
+ port = 49153,    
+ user = "root",    
+ password = "Camplovers01")

Error in DBconnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname = "sakila", host = "192.168.50.71", :    
unused arguments (dbname = "sakila", host = "192.168.50.71", port = 49153, user = "root", password = "Camplovers01")
```

The question then is when I pass a function like above how can I make sure I pass the correct arguments? [Function I am trying to pass](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DBI/versions/0.5-1/topics/dbConnect)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, asked and then answered by myself. The answer is in the error, unused arguments. I need to place the arguments from the source function in the function I create. These will pass through to the original function and return the correct response. The odbcListDrivers worked as it had no arguments to pass or expect.
**Example**
*Old .R file*

```
#'    
#' u/export    
#'    
DBconnect <- function() {    
DBI::dbConnect()    
}
```

This of course fails as was the reason for my question.
*New .R file*

```
#'
#' @export
#'
DBconnect <- function(dsn = NULL,
                      ...,
                      timezone = "UTC",
                      timezone_out = "UTC",
                      encoding = "",
                      bigint = c("integer64", "integer", "numeric", "character"),
                      timeout = Inf,
                      driver = NULL,
                      server = NULL,
                      database = NULL,
                      uid = NULL,
                      pwd = NULL,
                      dbms.name = NULL,
                      .connection_string = NULL) {
  DBI::dbConnect()
}
```

Finding the arguments of the function was a simple matter of reviewing the .R file in the GitHub repo for the Package in question.